# how to create template path for .js file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i just lrned how to create template path for .js file-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>js/scripts.js" ></script>
```

but inside my 'scripts.js' file has included some .js files like below:

> include('js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');
>
> include('js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js');
>
> include('js/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min.js');
>
> include('js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js');
>
> .....and so on

any1 pls help me how can i make path for those included .js file in easiest way. i'm vry new in wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just change it to

```
include( "jquery.easing.1.3.js" );
```

etc. So without the "js/".

If I understand correctly, you're including files in the javascript file scripts.js that are in the same directory.

Including files without prepending a `/` always means you're searching through the current directory. So basically, you're trying to include `js/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js`, which doesn't exist.

EDIT:
If you're trying to use a PHP include inside a Javascript file, it will not work. You shouldn't do the including in the Javascript file anyway, just do it in the file you're including scripts.js as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>js/scripts.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" ></script>
```

etc.

Comment: @RadicalRaid..thanks i hv tried ur ways but its provide me netwrok err.. & u r right all js files stored in same directory. would u pls advise if hv way smthing like: <script type="text/javascript">
var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';
</script>

Comment: Can you give me the complete error you get? My guess is there are some files missing. Maybe try it like `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/scripts.js" ></script>` (an extra `/` before js).

Comment: sry 4 late reply; having err: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/tiffany/projects/jquery.easing.1.3.js"`. in my header file i changed it to `<?php 
$templateDirPath = get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/'; ?>` & `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $templateDirPath; ?>js/scripts.js"></script>` & all of my js files stored in single folder named js

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to include the JS files in the theme:

```
include(get_bloginfo('template_url') . 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');
include(get_bloginfo('template_url') . 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js');
include(get_bloginfo('template_url') . 'js/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min.js');
include(get_bloginfo('template_url') . 'js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js');
```

Cheers

Or if your purpose is to embed all JS files contents in one JS file, you should use the following, This will use the file path of the files, not the URL addresses:

```
include(get_template_directory() . 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');
include(get_template_directory() . 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js');
include(get_template_directory() . 'js/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min.js');
include(get_template_directory() . 'js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js');
```

Answer (score -1):

`bloginfo( 'template_directory' );`

is the correct way because wordpress themes require the complete path.

and if you want to use  `include()` then use something like this :

`include(bloginfo('template_directory') . 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js')`

Comment: @RadicalRaid, yes you are right, but the `include()` function is just for PHP not for JS.

Comment: Sorry, some miscommunication there. Shouldn't `bloginfo(...)` be replaced by `get_bloginfo(...)` seeing that `bloginfo(...)` echoes its value directly?

Comment: @RadicalRaid the only difference between `get_bloginfo()` and `bloginfo()` is, you can use `filters` in `get_bloginfo()` otherwise everything is same like `blog_info()` to know more please follow the link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Comment: From http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/bloginfo :
"It can be used anywhere within a page template. This always prints a result to the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, use get_bloginfo()."